# Duda consulta en otra tabla Mysql

Tags: mysql

Tengo en una consulta y subconsulta la cantidad que ha vendido uno de mis empleados, la max. Pero no consigo sacar el nombre de su encargado, que también está en la tabla de "Trabajadores". ¿Alguna idea?

```
select max(maximo) from
(select 
       nombre, apellido1, apellido2, 
       sum(cantidad*preciounidad) as maximo 
       from trabajadores, clientes, pedidos, detallepedidos
       where 
       trabajadores.codigotrabajador = clientes.codigotrabajadorrepventas 
       AND clientes.codigocliente = pedidos.codigocliente 
       AND detallepedidos.codigopedido = pedidos.codigopedido
       group by nombre, apellido1, apellido2 order by maximo
) as max2;
```

Comment: Cual es el nombre del encargado? lo sacaste en esa query?

Comment: si si.. y cual es? porque estas haciendo como mucho lio para un query tan simple. Tambien, no hay un id de empleado en la tabla trabajadoreS?

Comment: podes mostrar la estructura de las tablas y donde esta cada cosa? solo queres mostrar la suma y el nombre del jefe o algo mas?

Comment: No puedo ver fotos. Por favor, pone la estructura en la pregunta. Aclara todos los campos que necesitas. usa el boton [edit] y pone toda la informacion en la pregunta.

Comment: acabo de editar, a ver si te sirve, gracias

Comment: No entiendo nada de tu edicion. Esos 3 campos en tu select son el nombre del jefe? Y solo queres un solo nombre que sea el de mayor ventas?

Comment: No victor. Arregla la pregunta. podes subir imagenes en la misma si queres. Necesitamos que nos digas cuales son los campos con el nombre de los jefes, en que tablas estan, y que queres mostrar como salida de tu consulta.

Comment: asi esta mejor?

Comment: Porque borraste la unica aprte que hacia a tu pregunta contestable?

Comment: Porque seguis borrando de la pregunta la unica parte que sirve? que problema tenes?

Answer (score 2):

Separemos tu query en pedazos... porque va a ser mucho mas simple.

Lo primero es obtener el empleado con mas ventas

```
select 
CodigoEmpleado,
CodigoJefe
sum(cantidad*preciounidad) as maximo 
from trabajadores, clientes, pedidos, detallepedidos
where 
trabajadores.codigotrabajador = clientes.codigotrabajadorrepventas 
AND clientes.codigocliente = pedidos.codigocliente 
AND detallepedidos.codigopedido = pedidos.codigopedido
group by CodigoEmpleado,CodigoJefe
order by sum(cantidad*preciounidad) desc
```

Ahora, ahi tenemos a todos los empleados y la suma de sus ventas.

Si a esta consulta la usamos como entrada de otra, vamos a tener lo siguiente:

```
Select CodigoJefe, maximo 
from (
    select 
    CodigoEmpleado,
    CodigoJefe,
    sum(cantidad*preciounidad) as maximo 
    from trabajadores, clientes, pedidos, detallepedidos
    where 
    trabajadores.codigotrabajador = clientes.codigotrabajadorrepventas 
    AND clientes.codigocliente = pedidos.codigocliente 
    AND detallepedidos.codigopedido = pedidos.codigopedido
    group by CodigoEmpleado,CodigoJefe
    order by sum(cantidad*preciounidad) desc 
) as t Limit 1
```

Esto nos va a traer solo un registro ;)

Si queremos el nombre del jefe, podemos cambiar el select anterior, por uno que haga lo siguiente:

```
select (select nombre from empleados e where e.codigoempleado=t.CodigoJefe), etc
```

Tu consulta debe quedar de la siguiente forma:

```
Select (select nombre from empleados e where e.codigoempleado=t.CodigoJefe), maximo 
from (
    select 
    CodigoEmpleado,
    CodigoJefe,
    sum(cantidad*preciounidad) as maximo 
    from trabajadores, clientes, pedidos, detallepedidos
    where 
    trabajadores.codigotrabajador = clientes.codigotrabajadorrepventas 
    AND clientes.codigocliente = pedidos.codigocliente 
    AND detallepedidos.codigopedido = pedidos.codigopedido
    group by CodigoEmpleado,CodigoJefe
    order by sum(cantidad*preciounidad) desc 
) as t Limit 1
```

Comment: no sale lo del nombre del boss... es lo unico que me falta. gracias

Comment: a que te referis con que no sale? y que te sale? @Victor

Comment: Esto devuelve "empty set" --> select nombre from empleados e where e.codigoempleado=CodigoJefe

Comment: Ahi le puse un alias a la consulta exterior. Fijate si ahora te funciona @Victor

Comment: Porque cambiaste el from? en ningun lado te dije que lo cambiaras... :/ @Victor

Comment: ahora si! me faltan solo los apellidos :/

Comment: Es lo mismo que para los nombres.. mas selects ;) @Victor

Answer (score 0):

Para obtener el nombre del encargado de un trabajador puedes utilizar una relación recursiva, la cual indica que una tabla se relaciona consigo misma. Por ejemplo, una relación de Trabajadores-Trabajadores. En este caso una tabla representa al rol de encargado y la otra al rol de un trabajador subordinado. Te dejo un ejemplo de como sería esta relación para que la adaptes según lo que requieras.

```
SELECT 
    t.nombre,
    t.apellido1, 
    t.apellido2, 
    s.nombre, 
    s.apellido1, 
    s.apellido2 
 FROM 
    Trabajadores AS t 
 JOIN
    Trabajadores AS s 
 ON 
    t.codigojefe = s.codigotrabajador;
```

En la anterior consulta el alias "t" hace referencia al trabajador subordinado y el alias "s" al encargado, mientras que, "codigojefe" sería tu llave foránea.